# Memory usage window of Flutter Performance does not show anything

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Snippet of Flutter Performance tap]

Is there any flag that I need to enable so that the 'Memory usage' window will show something instead of empty?

Comment: Hey. Did by any chance you find the solution? Cause from almost 2 hours after you posted this, I've been checking for the same answer as well.

Comment: nope, still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 6):

When I had the same problem, going to

File -> Invalidate cache & restart

worked for me